# Writing manual parser

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar, lr-grammar, earley-parser

I need write a parser manually. Can`t choose between LL(*) and LR (maybe try Earley?). Should I use bottom-up parsing, because grammar for LL will be rather difficult?

Comment: It depends in large part on what kind of language you're trying to parse.  Without more information about your application, it's impossible to give any kind of reasonable suggestion.  You might also want to look at the "Related" questions (scroll down and look to the right).  There are lots of questions here about parsing, and lots of good discussion.

Comment: Why do you *need* to write a parser manually?  There's generally not a lot of value in this.

Comment: I can`t use yacc or other parsers, where my parser will work

Comment: Why not? They produce some tables and some code.  Surely where you will put your parser, allows some tables and some code.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, I should try their tables

Answer (score 2):

I would go with either a recursive descent parser or maybe a tail-recursive descent parser (i.e. LL) or a top-down operator precedence parser.

The LR family of parsers, whether that be LR, LALR(k), LALR(1), GLR or whatever are just too "weird" to keep in your head. If you try to write one of those, you generally end up implementing a parser generator *anyway*, just to stay sane.

Comment: Oh nonsense. I've been using LALR since 1979 without any necessity to implement my own parser generator.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest type of parser to write by hand is a recursive descent parser, which is in the family of LL parsers.  most other types of parser are either difficult to write by hand (LALR parsers, which use large state transition tables) or are for parsing complex languages (such as Earley parsers for parsing natural languages).

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) has some good information on recursive descent parsing.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the grammar you try to use. LL has some troubles with uncertainities in grammars (you'll have to make everything left-recursion free).

If you cannot decide, go with LR(1) or LALR. Maybe even GLR.

Answer (score 0):

Try [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). It is for you. Create your language, parser and editor fast and easy

Comment: I tried it, and I was very impressed too :D